# Clone entire Wordpress site without server access using Python

Tags: python, wordpress, web-crawler

I'm trying to save the contents of an entire Wordpress site using python and without ftp / server access.  In other words, I want to save a "complete copy, or closest possible" of the Wordpress site to disk and I can't download everything from ftp / server.

I've found some options to iterate through the various pages that make up the site, but nothing that will "save the site as a whole."

Comment: I would start by simply downloading the full html pages and storing them in a directory structure that maps to the site (this will by its very nature capture a "complete copy" of the site). You can easily write a Python script to do that. Then you can work out what further processing you want to do offline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to use Python and nothing else, you could use [wpull](http://wpull.readthedocs.org/en/master/index.html), which is a wget clone written in Python. They have an example for archiving/downloading an entire website in their docs.

```
wpull billy.blogsite.example --warc-file blogsite-billy \
--no-check-certificate \
--no-robots --user-agent "InconspiuousWebBrowser/1.0" \
--wait 0.5 --random-wait --waitretry 600 \
--page-requisites --recursive --level inf \
--span-hosts --domains blogsitecdn.example,cloudspeeder.example \
--hostnames billy.blogsite.example \
--reject-regex "/login\.php"  \
--tries inf --retry-connrefused --retry-dns-error \
--delete-after --database blogsite-billy.db \
--quiet --output-file blogsite-billy.log
```

Answer (score 2):

Not using python (although I'm sure you could hack up something -- or possibly find something on pypi), but why not just use wget. Something like:

```
wget -rkp -l3 -np -nH --cut-dirs=1 http://example.com
```

Of course if you REALLY want to do it in python, you could:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(['wget', '-rkp', '-l3', '-np', '-nH', '--cut-dirs=1', 'http://example.com'])
```

Comment: This worked for me in a case I would had expected not. Much thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you can, and you should, mantain all WordPress modeling tables, you might want to use a WordPress feature (also plugin) called Migrate...You might have it, so, if you can go to your Administration Panel (aka /wp-admin) you can loggin and use
http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/export.php
This way, you will get a XML that you can use to import to your python project. There are also some plugins that export a full .sql file

Remember, all content is basically into the MySQL tables, so that all you need there